# DAO is not being Autowired while running tests under MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I need to test parserService. Unfortunately it shows that RecordDao object suppose ot be Autowired but it's not, it's remains `null` while running test. How to fix it?

**ParserControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ParserControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ParserService parserService;

    private ParserController parserController;

    @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        parserController = new ParserController(parserService);
    }

    @Test
    public void parseFileToRecordEntity(){
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("exampleLog.txt"));
            List<Record> records =  parserService.parse(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
            for(Record r: records){
                System.out.println(r.toString());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**SERVICE**

```
@Service("parserService")
public class ParserService {

    @Autowired
    RecordDao recordDao;

public List<Record> parse(byte[] fileBytes) {
//....
if(!records.isEmpty()){
            for(Record r: records){
                recordDao.save(r);
            }
        }

        return records;
}
}
```

**RecordDao**

```
import domain.Record;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface RecordDao extends CrudRepository<Record, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Use Spring not Mockito... Mockito knowns nothing about `@Autowired`. You should add a field `RecordDao` do your test and annotate that with `@Mock`.

Comment: I added `@Mock RecordDao recordDao;` Then removed `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. But same error

Comment: You shouldn't remove the `@RunWith` because that uses the Mockito based runner that understands `@Mock`. If you remove it the `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations are useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are explicitly testing your DAO, you should probably be mocking it.  You can spy on your service, then tell mockito to inject the mocked dao when you call its get method.

```
doReturn(mockDoa).when(parserService).getRecordDao()
```

If you are insistent on getting the real dao in there, then you should start a spring application context within your test and let spring manage all of your beans, rather than initialising them yourself.  The only reason autowired isnt working is because the servce was initialised manually and isnt part of any spring context, therefore spring dosent know about it, and doesnt know that it requires a dao!